# Windows Sandbox for executables

Tags: windows, security, sandbox

I am looking for a Sandbox system on Windows like [nsjail](https://github.com/google/nsjail). I found a few software packages as real sandboxes like VMs, but I wrote a server software I would like to additionally sandbox. For example:

```
$ C:\Users\Foo\Documents\my-server\> sandbox.exe C:\Users\Foo\Documents\my-server\ start.exe
```

The sandbox limits read-write access to C:\Users\Foo\Documents\my-server\ and the process cannot escape there. Any help is highly appreciated!